# How do I find similar commands in terminal?

Tags: command-line

I know about the "clear" command but I accidentally typed "cls" instead. I then received a message that said.

```
No command 'cls' found, but there are 18 similar ones
```

so what is the significance of telling me there are 18 similar commands and is there a way to see the commands that terminal mentioned?

Comment: You should look at Oh My Zsh!

Comment: @AndyFriese you are correct it is a duplicate. I didn't see that question. The top answer for that question answers my questions sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash gives suggestions when unknown commands are entered.

```
$ apr
No command 'apr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'arp' from package 'net-tools' (main)
 Command 'apm' from package 'apmd' (main)
 Command 'apf' from package 'apf-firewall' (universe)
 Command 'apg' from package 'apg' (main)
 Command 'pr' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'gpr' from package 'gpr' (universe)
 Command 'ar' from package 'binutils' (main)
 Command 'ar' from package 'binutils-multiarch' (universe)
 Command 'par' from package 'par' (universe)
 Command 'lpr' from package 'lpr' (universe)
 Command 'lpr' from package 'lprng' (universe)
 Command 'lpr' from package 'gnuspool' (universe)
 Command 'lpr' from package 'cups-bsd' (main)
apr: command not found
```

If there are two many possibilities then bash just tells how many there are. Indeed, not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like

```
man -k '^cl'
```

This would list all the man pages that start with 'cl'. Not a direct match to your question but gives you other commands like clear, clearenv, clock etc.